# Unknown PHP output image error

Tags: javascript, php, image, save

First I know its annoying to have so much text instead of code to display the error, its just I'm not sure where I should start debugging, and therefore I will complement the thread as I go.

Here is the thing, I have a page where I have to upload multiple images and edit them in the browser. For that matter I developed javascript code where you can upload and edit the image inside a canvas and then output it to a hidden input.
Since the number of images a variable, another javascript function is necessary to create multiple inputs for new images.

Those images are, them, uploaded with other data by a post form. The process in which the post is processed is page_with_form --> process_form_page --> redirect_to_page, which is used to save the data into the database and the images to the server.

When uploading these multiple images in my local server no error is generated, but when I upload the code to the web server the script go bananas.

Every time I post the form WITH a multiple image (without the image uploaded the post is successful) an error occurs, but not always the same error. I had many different errors occurring actually.

The errors variate from outputting gibberish, like this:

```
‰PNG  IHDR´ð©NH IDATxœd»wTUY‚¾]Ó=Ý=ÓSªzª«ÚŠ†2'Ì ”œsÎ9HF‚"* ‚ˆ(*"¨¨˜³¥‚JÎ9Þtn«»ºº,y~`÷Ì|ßï:÷œ³îZg­óœw½{ïw°nñ "üqýF› B|Ùüù·¬ž±-_,ä›ßþ‰­Ÿ~Ég¿þÛ¿YÀŸ~ó[>úÕò›_þ]]<6êâ±b5Ñ!DúcôÙ7|ò«?¢÷ç/0ûbž³çá2k!!u\¯CøcÂ,pÒÞIl`8q»¢‰ÛElhñÑ1ÄFEMLp±þaÄEÆCLxÑ»¢‰ $&$‚˜bÃ£‰Š!66–¸Ø8â"£ˆ%>>žøø8’““IJˆ'1Ò„]>$z¹ëCÒ.7LV.ÂJ{úØmYI‰Û7šà¦§ƒî‚o°Ú¢EB’É»ˆõ7#ÖÛ„Ä]$„†ëJ´‹^;vadI˜Ž þëôpÑ5ÃtËV¶,^ŠÉÆ,ÿf6+gÎa§ÖZÌÖ¯'f—+ZŸ.ÄDk«–aµr#Kþ¬…Ùúõ˜¬]‰ÅÆÍ¬œ¹„¿ü~&[V`ªãÄWÿ=—û¿ÿøÝoþÀï~óG>üõïøÏû-‰‰IìÙ³—øøxbcc‰%&&...
```

Or giving an errors like:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in E:\Home\gerenciamentodelegac\Web\documents\imgs\tatoos\51d115e8909cc397141e9a39651fa88a6d7302aeaee4248d257b8c8f16bf87ba.png on line 18

PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ')' in E:\Home\gerenciamentodelegac\Web\documents\imgs\tatoos\d8e6765d3ab791adce3b325f6a1b8270e244a70df3739f34202f9158fa540f80.png on line 46
```

Or it just does not redirect to any page or show any error, it sits on the same page, and if a try to upload again a new error is generated:

```
PHP Warning:  include(documents/imgs/tatoos/97ebacba3f87fd2477bb74a523fcc4810002a474b569b43b485ddac7c885ede5.png) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in E:\Home\gerenciamentodelegac\Web\fetch_page.php on line 70
PHP Warning:  include() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Failed opening 'documents/imgs/tatoos/97ebacba3f87fd2477bb74a523fcc4810002a474b569b43b485ddac7c885ede5.png' for inclusion (include_path='.;c:\PHP_5.3\includes') in E:\Home\gerenciamentodelegac\Web\fetch_page.php on line 70
```

But here is the crazy part: All the data is outputted correctly! The data is correctly saved to the database and the images are saved to the server.

Now, the local server uses PHP 5.5 and the web server uses PHP 5.3, and here is the code to save the image:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($tatoos); $i++) {
    if (!file_exists($tatoos[$i])) {
        $uri = substr($tatoos_src[$i], strpos($tatoos_src[$i], ",") + 1);
        $success = file_put_contents($tatoos[$i], base64_decode($uri));
    }
}
```

Where should I start trouble shooting? Any idea where the error may relies?

Comment: Have a look on your PHP code , It seems like you are sending base64 encoded string to backend? Have you handle the url safe characters problems ?